# Named Range Duplication/ Formula Altering

Tags: vba, excel, named

I am currently working within a tab with named ranges.  They are all associated with class 1.  I would like to duplicate these cells twice, creating identical columns for classes 2 and 3.  The named ranges should remain the same aside from a _2/_3 attached for the next two classes.  I also need the formulas to be changed within each column, but containing the correct suffix(_2/_3).

This is a simplified version to better explain what I am trying to do:

```
**Class 1** 

  Lives         
  Age       
  Adjust        
  Claim     
  Risk      

**Class1    Class2      Class3**

  Lives     Lives_2     Lives_3

  Age       Age_2       Age_3

  Adjust    Adjust_2    Adjust_3

  Claim     Claim_2     Claim_3

  Risk      Risk_2      Risk_3
```

These are representative of the *names* of the cells; they all also contain formulas linking within each class.  The class 1 area that is already completed has 9 columns and 120 rows.  I would like class two to populate column 10 to 18 and class 3 the next 9.  Here is the code I was working with to try to just change the names but I was unsuccessful:

```
Sub ChangeNames()
    Dim OldName As String
    Dim NewName2 As String
    Dim NewName3 As String
    Dim rng As Range



    For r = 1 To 127
        For c = 1 To 10
            If IsNamedRange(Cells(r, 1 + c)) Then
                    Set rng = Sheets("Medical").Cells(r, 1 + c)

                    OldName = rng.Name
                    NewName2 = OldName & "_2"
                    NewName3 = OldName & "_3"

                    Sheets("Medical").Cells(r, 11 + c).Name = NewName2
                    Sheets("Medical").Cells(r, 21 + c).Name = NewName3

            End If

        Next c
    Next r


End Sub
```

---

```
Function IsNamedRange(MyRange) As Boolean
    Dim vntName As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
        IsNamedRange = MyRange.Name <> ""
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Is this possible with VBA?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Sub names()
    Dim this As String
    Dim OldName As String
    Dim NewName2 As String
    Dim NewName3 As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

```
For Each this In Workbook.names
    If Range(this).Worksheet = "Medical" Then
        NewName2 = Range(this).Name & "_2"
        NewName3 = Range(this).Name & "_3"
        x = Range(this).Column
        y = Range(this).Row
        Sheets("Medical").Cells(x, 10 + y).Name = NewName2
        Sheets("Medical").Cells(x, 20 + y).Name = NewName3
    End If

Next this
```

End Sub

Comment: *Is this possible with VBA* - Yes. *but I was unsuccessful* - If you elaborate on what is not working, we can help you more.

Comment: When I run the above code; the old name variable has a value of "=Medical!$b$3" rather than Med_Prod which is the name of the cell -- how do I have it return the name range rather than cell location.  Let me know if I need to clarify further

Comment: are the names defined at the sheet level or workbook level?

Comment: the names are defined at the workbook level

Comment: this is going to be complex ... you are going to have to loop through the names collection in the workbook - make sure they are on the sheet you want, then define the column they are in, then use offset and a counter to set them to `*n*` columns over with the `name_*x*`

Comment: i have a shell code for you, but I don't know if it is completely what you need, but it's a good start. the reason I say this is because I don't fully understand how you want to define class2 and class3. The code I have will take a list of named ranges in column A and blow them out 9 times for each successive column and name them `name_2, name_3 ...`. I have a feeling that after seeing that code you will be able to modify it to suit your exact needs ... I can post as answer if you want?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean - I have information for class 1 in columns B through J; I currently have just copy pasted these columns into K through S (for class two) and T through Ab (class 3).  Columns B through J have several hundred NamedRanges and I am just trying to copy them over 10 rows and add the "_2" to the end.  I think if I see your code I would be able to alter it to include all the columns.  Sorry for the ambiguity, I added more code above that may make this make for sense.  Thanks for you help

Comment: okay, first let me see if i can alter it to exactly what you need now that its more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out, you may need to make small adjustments to the offset or tweaks to fit your exact data set, but I defined it as precisely as I could.

```
Sub ChangeNames()

    Dim rName As Name
    For Each rName In ThisWorkbook.Names

        If rName.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = "Medical" Then

            Select Case rName.RefersToRange.Column

                Case 2 To 10

                    For i = 1 To 2

                        Dim sName As String
                        sName = "=" & rName.RefersToRange.Offset(, i * 10).Parent.Name
                        sName = sName & "!" & rName.RefersToRange.Offset(, i * 10).Address
                        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add rName.Name.Name & "_" & i + 1, RefersTo:=sName

                    Next

            End Select

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Im getting an application or object defined error on the ***If rName.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = "Medical" Then*** line

Comment: What is the function of the with ws?  Wouldnt the refersToRange.Parent override the with ws?

Comment: and rName is still just being loaded with "=_tabName_!$A$15" rather than the Name of A15..

Comment: also wouldnt the parent of a name with a workbook scope be the workbook? not the worksheet name? I may just try and go a different route and remove all the named ranges so that the formulas will not copy from the incorrect class section

Comment: @Brian - the code worked flawlessly for me. I deleted the `ws` stuff (it was left over from testing). Also, I changed `.rName.Name` to `rName.Name.Name` ... see if that helps. Also `Name.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` would be a `Worksheet` name, since the `RefersToRange` is at the worksheet level.

Comment: I threw an Or Error Resume Next and it worked flawlessly.  Thanks a ton

Comment: @Brian - A bit dangerous, but glad you got it to work.

Comment: did you have any suggestions for a direction I could go for changing all the formulas to reference the correct class?  This will be very tricky as most of the cells have reference to multiple names, and some of these names are not to be changed.  Basically all of the names that were changed are the names that need to be updated within the formulas.  Currently all of the formulas for class 2 and 3 reference the named ranges for class 1, if this makes sense

Comment: @brian - there has to be systematic way to use manually `Find/Replace` on the specific ranges.

Comment: that was the route I had planned on going; unfortunately many of the named ranges are ambiguous in nature.. i.e. cell_name and cell_name_specifics within each class. So when I search for cell_name and replace with cell_name_2 in class 2, it also changes cell_name_specifics to cell_name_2_specifics